# Scrolling ticker in HTML with date, time, and location

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, geolocation

I would like to create a scrolling ticker in HTML, displaying the CURRENT date, time and location on the scrolling ticker.

I already have a scrolling ticker, but I don't know how to add time, date, and location to it. I know that it has something to do with geolocation, I would like to know how to display the CURRENT date, time and location on the scrolling ticker.

the code I have is shown below

```
      <div class="hwrap"><div class="hmove">
        <div class="hitem"> The time is:     </div>
         <div class="hitem"> The date is:   </div>
          <div class="hitem"> The location is: </div>
      </div></div>
```

```
    .hwrap {
       overflow: hidden; /* HIDE SCROLL BAR */
        background: #eee;
      }
      .hmove { display: flex; }
      .hitem {
      flex-shrink: 0;
       width: 100%;
       box-sizing: border-box;
        padding: 10px;
         text-align: center;
            }
  
           /* (D) ANIMATION - MOVE ITEMS FROM RIGHT TO LEFT */
          /* 4 ITEMS -400%, CHANGE THIS IF YOU ADD/REMOVE ITEMS */
      @keyframes tickerh {
       0% {transform: translate3d (100%, 0, 0);}
        100% {transform: translate3d (-400%, 0, 0);}
        }
      .hmove {animation: tickerh linear 15s infinite;}
      .hmove:hover {animation-play-state: paused;}
```

Comment: Not really clear what your actual question is supposed to be here. If you want a time to show after `The time is:` - well then _write_ a time value in that position ...?

Comment: I'm trying to get the actual current time, date and location, possibly using geolocation.

Comment: Current local time & date you get from the client already. How geolocation works, you can read up on yourself a bit first. Make an attempt, and show your results here.

Comment: I've already read geolocation, I would like to use geolocation on the scrolling ticker, and I need some assistance with that.

Comment: You might want to take a look at ["_Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?_"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/20170164)